# Windows folder lock 7 forgotten password

Tags: directory, window, lock

I have a locked file with `.flkb` extension which is a locker in folder lock 7 software in Windows 7. I have forgotten the password of that locker and now I cannot access files in that folder.

Is there way to open that folder using Ubuntu? I know the master password of folder lock 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can never be certain until you try but:

1. There is no Linux version of that software
2. There is no compatibility information on that software in [wine.org's compatibility DB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=application&sTitle=Browse+Applications&iItemsPerPage=25&iPage=1&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true)

So I'd say your chances are extremely slim to non-existent...

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If one of the answers *solved your problem*, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is the most useful of all](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: @AnujAggarwal: don't thank me, please click the little grey check mark turning it into a beautiful green.